# эффект нажатия кнопки

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, у меня в середине кнопки не активность, слева и справа эффект нажатия есть, а вот именно по середине нету, это когда я выравнивание справа делаю, такая проблема, как её убрать?

```
<p align="right">
<style>
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;  
}

a:hover span{
  background: #aaaaaa;
}

a span {
  display:inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: .67rem;
  height: 39px;
  line-height: 39px;
  width: 115px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #6f7075;
}

a img {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<a href="http://www.123contactform.com/form-2169330/-" ><img border="0" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/acfb6e3f8f7771c1c4cd0c74a9822ec9/1472759469/599/1065900/PRYPer.gif"><span>ЗАКАЗАТЬ ЗВОНОК</span></a>
```

Comment: Какая неактивность? Всё тут активно. Вы еще кстати забыли тэг <p> закрыть.

Comment: Кстати зачем вам грузить картинку и не показывать ее?

Comment: Я добавил в запись картинку

Answer (score 2):

Возможно из-за того, что параграф `p` был не закрыт.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;  
}

a:hover span{
  background: #aaaaaa;
}

a span {
  display:inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: .67rem;
  height: 39px;
  line-height: 39px;
  width: 115px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #6f7075;
}

a img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p align="right">
    <a href="http://www.123contactform.com/form-2169330/-" ><img border="0" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/acfb6e3f8f7771c1c4cd0c74a9822ec9/1472759469/599/1065900/PRYPer.gif">
      <span>ЗАКАЗАТЬ ЗВОНОК</span>
    </a>
</p>
```